# Random variables in weak$^*$-dual of Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space with weak$^*$ dual $X'$ and $T_n, T$ random variables in $X'$ (with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra). Assume that $T_n x \to T x$ in distribution for all $x \in X$. Then clearly for each $x \in X$ the sequence $T_n x$ is bounded in probability (= tight), i.e. $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \, \exists C_{\varepsilon, x} > 0: \, \sup_n P(|T_n x| > C_{\varepsilon, x}) < \varepsilon$. Does it follow that the sequence of dual norms $\lVert T_n \rVert$ is bounded in probability as well, i.e. $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \, \exists C_{\varepsilon} > 0: \, \sup_n P(\lVert T_n \rVert > C_{\varepsilon}) < \varepsilon$?

Comment: What is the "weak* dual"???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich $X'$ is the dual of $(X, \lVert \cdot \rVert)$ equipped with the weak$^*$ topology, i.e. for $f_n, f \in X'$ it holds $f_n \to f$ iff $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x \in X$.

Comment: If you said "$X$ with the weak* topology" that would be perfectly clear. If I I read "the weak dual" I'd assume that meant the dual of $(X,\tau_{\text{weak}})$, hence my confusion here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true. The following example is essentially the one in http://www.numdam.org/item/10.5802/aif.249.pdf, Exemple I.6.4.

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space (for example $\mathcal{H} = \ell^2$).
Choose an orthonormal basis $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and define $T_n$ via
$$T_n x = \langle n  e_{J^{(n)}}, \,x \rangle,$$ where $J^{(n)}$ is a $\mathbb{N}$-valued random variable with the distribution
$$
\mathbb{P}(J^{(n)} = j) = p_j^{(n)}
$$ to be specified.

First observe that $\Vert T_n \Vert = n$. Let us now see that we can choose $J^{(n)}$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(\vert T_n x \vert > \epsilon) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathcal{H}$ and all $\epsilon > 0$.

Let $$x = \sum_{j} x_j e_j \in \mathcal{H}$$ be given and $c := \sum_{j} \vert x_j\vert^2 <\infty$.

Now,
$$
\mathbb{P}(\vert T_n x \vert > \epsilon) = \mathbb{P}(\vert x_{J^{(n)}} \vert^2 > \epsilon^2 / n^2).
$$

As $\sum_j \vert x_j\vert^2 = c$, there are at maximum $\lceil c n^2 / \epsilon^2 \rceil$ of the $j$ such that $\vert x_j\vert^2 > \epsilon^2/n^2$.
If the probabilities $p_j^{(n)}$ are non-increasing, it follows that
$$
\mathbb{P}(\vert T_n x \vert > \epsilon) = \mathbb{P}(\vert x_{J^{(n)}} \vert^2 > \epsilon^2 / n^2) \leq \sum_{j = 0}^{\lceil c n^2 / \epsilon^2 \rceil - 1} p_j^{(n)} 
$$.

To ensure convergence, we now just need to choose good $p_j^{(n)}$.
You can either follow the link above or try it yourself (with for example a geometric distribution).

Comment: That's a very enlightening counterexample. Thank you. To construct such a sequence $p_j^{(n)}$ one can start playing around with $\sum_{j=0}^n \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{j+n}$ which converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ (and then modify accordingly). You say that you assume the $p_j^{(n)}$ to be non-decreasing (in $j$?) - but how is that possible if the $p_j^{(n)} \to 0$ as $j \to \infty$ for fixed $n$? I still believe one can nevertheless construct a similar upper bound on the r.h.s. (the sum) without demanding the $p_j^{(n)}$ to be non-decreasing.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right, this was a typo. The sequence should be non-increasing. The intuition is that the probability of getting smaller $j$ is indeed higher but as $n$ increases the probability mass flattens out and escapes to infinity.

Comment: I tried to transfer your construction to $X = C[0,1]$. In your counterexample for $\ell^2$ it is essential that the components $x_j$ of $x$ converge to $0$ as $j \to \infty$. This does not work in $C[0,1]$: for $f \in C[0,1]$ with $f > 0$ it holds $\inf_x f(x) > 0$. So maybe the conjecture is true for (at least) $X = C[0,1]$?